# Share functions across classes without runtime polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have many different matrix classes that represent the different kind of storages that a matrix can use. For example static and dynamic arrays like this:

```
class mat_d
{
    float arr[3][4];
}
class mat_s
{
    float** arr;
}
```

All matrix classes have access operators using `operator()(uint32 r, uint32 c)`. They will obviously have to be implemented for every class separately. All matrices also have functions that can be applied on them, like `transpose()` which returns a new matrix. This function looks exactly the same for all matrices, since it uses the `operator()` which all matrices have in common. How can I share the function across my matrix classes?

Here's what I don't want to do:

- Have common base class for all matrices with `virtual .. operator()` to be used inside the base methods and to be overridden by the different storage matrices. (Causes virtual function overhead)
- New matrix class containing all base methods with a template parameter that represents the storage policy used and a member variable of that type. (Can only call constructors of storage policy member through constructors of base class; overhead when accessing elements, since the access operator has to be called twice)

I know all information is present at compile-time for the compiler to know which matrix class is used in which case. The only solution that I can think of right now is to define a macro with all base methods and then use that macro in all matrix classes, but that would just be really ugly.

Comment: You have templates in your tags. Is having templated non-member functions acceptable for you? (i.e. `transpose(matrix)`)

Comment: Right, that would work. I would still prefer member functions though; could I somehow use the curiously recurring template pattern to solve this? To tell the base class which storage is used. I can only think of something ugly like this `(*((S*) this))(r, c)` to access the elements, where S is the storage template parameter, i.e. the matrix subclass. Does the conversion happen at compile-time or does it cause an overhead at run-time?

Comment: The CRTP is the most obvious answer, unless I misunderstand some of your goals.  Almost all the apparent extra overhead you seem to be worrying about vanishes in an optimized build assuming that overhead is represented in inlinable functions of a templated class.

Comment: The conversion `(*((S*)this))` is inherently completely free at run-time either when the derived class has no virtual functions or when the base class has virtual functions.  (I'm assuming simple inheritance).   For an efficient template design, you probably want no virtual functions.  Even when the conversion is not inherently free, it is likely to be free when calling a fully inlined operation.

Comment: Use `static_cast<>` instead of a C-style conversion, though.

Comment: Yup, thanks. That should do it :)

Comment: Your second option that you don't want to do is probably the way to go. It is not very clear why you are not content with it. There will be no overhead since all forwarding accessors will be inlined. CRTP is one possible realization of this but not the only one.

Comment: I had my matrices setup the way I described it in the second option, and a function that simply sets the contents of a row was still slower than a similar function in Eigen, with -O3 enabled. That's why I wanted to test different options including the CRTP to see if they're faster.

Comment: The constructors will be uglier in your original second option than in CRTP and there will be some trivial extra overhead compared to CRTP, but unlikely enough to make a measurable difference.  I would need to see code to be sure, but I would not expect the performance problem in your second option would be due to the extra call layers (that the optimizer should have completely removed).